# What is the "Likut" in the Beur HaGr"a?

Tags: shulchan-aruch, vilna-gaon

Certain explanations of the Beur HaGr"a start with the word "Likut". Does that mean that those explanations were collected from other places the Gr"a wrote other than the Shulchan Aruch? If not what does it mean?

Comment: I beileve that the Gra initially wrote a peirush Biur Hagra and then added things on after he completed it, those additions are the likutim that he added. Will try and find source

Comment: I believe that it is referring to a sefer from one of the primary students of the Vilna Gaon, Rabbi Yitzchok Isaac Chaver who wrote Likkut HaGra. Another companion volume that was published with it is his book Sefer Od Yosef Chai which is a secondary source to authenticate many of the teachings attributed to the Vilna Gaon from Sefer Kol HaTor.